# Pyglet: fireball shooter, fireballs keep accelerating whenever I press a specified key instead of keeping constant speed

Tags: python, pyglet

How do you make this code work? Just have `pyglet` installed and change `"fireball.png"` with the name of an image stored in the directory where you saved this code to a file.

```
import pyglet

class Fireball(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, batch):
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, pyglet.resource.image("fireball.png"))
        # replace "fireball.png" with your own image stored in dir of fireball.py
        self.x =  10 # Initial x coordinate of the fireball
        self.y =  10 # Initial y coordinate of the fireball

class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, width = 315, height = 220)
        self.batch_draw = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()
        self.fireball = []

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.fps_display.draw()
        self.batch_draw.draw()
        if len(self.fireball) != 0:             # Allow drawing of multiple
            for i in range(len(self.fireball)): # fireballs on screen
                self.fireball[i].draw()         # at the same time

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.A:
            self.fireball.append(Fireball(batch = self.batch_draw))
            pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(func = self.update, interval = 1/60.)
            print "The 'A' key was pressed"

    def update(self, interval):
        for i in range(len(self.fireball)):
            self.fireball[i].x += 1 # why do fireballs get faster and faster?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Game()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

This code creates a black background screen, where the fps are displayed and a fireball is shot along the x direction from the position (10, 10) whenever you press the `A` key.

You will notice that the more fireballs you shoot, the faster all fireballs will start to go.

### Questions:

1. Why do the fireballs go faster and faster each time I press A ?
2. How should I stop the fireballs from accelerating each time I press A ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fireball goes faster and faster because every time you press the <kbd>A</kbd> you add another call of `self.update` to the scheduler. So `self.update` is called more and more times each time resulting in more updates of the position. To fix that move the line below to the `__init__()`.

```
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(func = self.update, interval = 1/60.)
```